# SQL Server stored procedure does not return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with some data and I have written a stored procedure to return a count of the rows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_User_Case_Answer_Found]
    @userID BIGINT,
    @visitID BIGINT
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM User_Case_Answer
        WHERE userID = @userID
          AND pvisitID = @visitID
GO
```

and when I execute it I get:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_User_Case_Answer_Found]
        @userID = 26,
        @visitID = 5

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

But the return value = 0? I am sure the table contains data.

Comment: pretty sure that will just be interpreted as two statements. A `return` without a value followed by a `select`. And the select will never run as you just exited

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure for this?  You can use a function instead.  Or at least an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: Aside: Do you need a precise `count` or are you merely trying to determine if a row `exists`?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the query in parenthesis.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_User_Case_Answer_Found]
    @userID BIGINT,
    @visitID BIGINT
AS
   return (SELECT count (*) 
    FROM User_Case_Answer
    WHERE userID = @userID
    AND pvisitID = @visitID)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9869ea123fe4f621417494eb7b244e94)

Comment: This is an improper us of a return within a stored procedure.

Comment: @b_stil improper in what way? Your own answer suggests that `RETURN @count` would be acceptable so if you don't have any objection to returning counts as return values why do you need the intermediate variable?

Comment: @MartinSmith I remove the `RETURN @count` from my answer as that isn't appropriate either and I wasn't thinking straight when I added that to my answer.  RETURN is meant to be an exit/stop execution construct in T-SQL not a way to return a result set. [T-SQL Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return` from the `SELECT` statement in the stored procedure.  It isn't needed.  You would use `return` if you are trying to short circuit and not return a result set or if you are returning a status code such as `RETURN 1`.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_User_Case_Answer_Found]
        @userID BIGINT
        ,@visitID BIGINT
    AS
           SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM User_Case_Answer
           WHERE userID = @userID
               AND pvisitID = @visitID;
    GO
```

You don't need to bind a return value when calling the procedure either.

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_User_Case_Answer_Found] @userID = 26, @visitID = 5
```

A return value parameter would be needed if you are using an output parameter.
[T-SQL RETURN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)